# Locate index of mismatch in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array that should contain the same value throughout and if there are mismatches, I want to pull the index of those mismatches.

Example:

```
[1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]
```

Output:

```
[4, 8]
```

What's the best way to accomplish this in Ruby/Rails?

Comment: Do you know upfront that you are looking for non-1 elements in the array? Or do you have to figure out what element is the most common first before searching the mismatches?

Comment: I suspect `#tally` and `#group_by` will be useful.

Comment: No, cannot assume that.  I simply used 1 as an example.

Comment: What if you have `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5]`? ie, the most common value is both `1` and `2` in this case.

Comment: What will you do with the indices of the "mismatches"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the most common element via [`tally`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) and [`max_by`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

most_common = arr.tally.max_by(&:last).first
#=> 1
```

`tally` returns a hash containing the number of occurrences for each element (`{1=>10, 3=>1, 2=>1}`), `max_by(&:last)` returns the pair with the most occurrences and `first` returns that element's value. (assuming there's always *one* most common element)

To get the indices, you can then utilize [`filter_map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map):

```
arr.each_with_index.filter_map { |e, i| i if e != most_common }
#=> [4, 8]
```

[`each_with_index`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) yields each element with its corresponding index. `filter_map` selects the truthy results from the block which returns the element's index if the element isn't equal to `1`. (and `nil` otherwise, which gets discarded)

Comment: ...or `arr.each_index.reject { |i| arr[i] == most_common }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's even shorter but somehow I dislike querying the array I'm already iterating.

Comment: We all have our foibles. I can't bring myself to using `compact`.

Answer (score 2):

Just another version:

```
[1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]
   .each_with_object(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] })
   .with_index { |(e, hash), i| hash[e] << i } # collect elements with their index
   .values                                     # only return the indexes
   .sort_by(&:size)                            # sort indexes arrays by size
   .slice(..-2)                                # return all but the longest
   .flatten                                    # flatten
#=> [4, 8]
```

Comment: Alternately `.values.then {|a| a.delete(a.max_by(&:size)) && a.flatten }` or derivatives there of e.g. `(a - [a.max_by(&:size)]).flatten`, `a.flatten.difference(a.max_by(&:size))`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
def find_non_matching_indexes(array, value)
  # Use `each_with_index` to iterate through the array with indexes
  array.each_with_index.select do |element, index|
    # Select elements where the value is not the given value
    element != value
  end.map(&:last) # Extract only the indexes from the selected elements
end
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't know the value beforehand.  We'd first need to identify the main value present in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_mismatch_indices(arr, main_value)
  arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i] != main_value }
end

my_array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
main_value = my_array.tally.max_by { |_, count| count }.first
result = find_mismatch_indices(my_array, main_value)

puts "Indices of mismatches: #{result.inspect}"
```

Output

```
Indices of mismatches: [4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to transform the data to identify where elements occur and how often.

```
>  a = [1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]
=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
> b = a.each_with_index.sort_by(&:first).group_by(&:first).transform_values { _1.map(&:last) }
=> {1=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2=>[10], 3=>[11]}
```

We then just need to exclude all but the most common element and extract the indexes.

```
> b.sort_by(&:length)[..-2].map { _1[1][0] }.sort
=> [4, 8]
```

Comment: I get different results when running that code.

Comment: We could clean up the initial Hash formation a little bit using `a.each_with_index.group_by(&:shift).transform_values(&:flatten)`

Comment: @Stefan what results do you get? I copied and pasted straight from IRB.

Comment: @Chris I get `{1=>[11, 1, 2, 3, 10, 0, 5, 6, 7, 9], 2=>[8], 3=>[4]}` for the former expression and `[8, 11]` for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tally` and `max_by` you are only accounting for a single most common.

Suppose you have these arrays:

```
arr1=[1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]  # should be [4,8]
arr2=[1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,2] # should be [9]?
arr3=[1,1,1,1,1,1] # should be []?
arr4=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] # should be []?
```

Then consider this approach that allows for more than one value or no value to be the 'most common':

```
def index_of_minority(arr)
    tal=arr.tally.sort_by(&:last).reverse
    most_common,rest=tal.partition{|e,cnt| cnt==tal[0][1]}.map{|sa| sa.to_h}
    arr.each_with_index.select{|e,i| rest.key?(e) }.map(&:last)
end
```

Then with those arrays:

```
[arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4].each{|arr| p index_of_minority(arr) }
[4, 8]
[9]
[]
[]
```